# django How to use subtration in views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I just want to subtract the total SchoolFeesMasterList(Amount) to StudentsEnrollmentRecord ESC(Amount)

this is my code in views.py

```
studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=1)
total_paid = list(SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.aggregate(Sum('Amount')).values()) or 0
discount = studentenroll.ESC.amount - total_paid
```

this is my models.py

```
class SchoolFeesMasterList(models.Model):
    Education_Levels= models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Payment_Types = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    School_Fees_Type= models.ForeignKey(SchoolFeesType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Amount =  models.FloatField()
    Amount_Per_Unit = models.FloatField()
    Effectivity_Date_From = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Effectivity_Date_To = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Remark = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)

class esc(models.Model):
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Grade Level With/without ESC"
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    strands = models.ForeignKey(strand, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    ESC = models.ForeignKey(esc, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
```

this is the error

[image]

Comment: And what error occurred when you run this? Isn't `total_paid` is a list object?

Comment: wailt I will post it, sorry I forgot

Comment: please see the update sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chenge this to:

```
studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=1).last()
total_paid = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.aggregate(Sum('Amount'))['Amount__sum'] or 0
discount = studentenroll.ESC.amount - total_paid
```

`studentenroll` without specifying the elemnt is QuerySet, not a single object. You can't access fields via QuerySet, but you can do that with single record.

Comment: where do you get that ['amount__sum']?

Comment: I get the same result when I copy your total_paid = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.aggregate(Sum('Amount'))['Amount__sum'] or 0
discount = studentenroll.ESC.amount - total_paid

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it (amount is in apper case). That's a field name you are using in `aggregate` method. You can rename it in this way `.aggregate(anothe_name=Sum('Amount'))`

Comment: @MaryRoseVillaganasOrcullo and did you used firs line from my example?

Comment: yes, I copy your answer but the error is still the same

Comment: exact same error? ESC could be null so it's possible there is no object and thus you can't get the amount from none. Please past the error text here.

Comment: sir why do you put .last() in studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=1).last()??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206661/discussion-between-mary-rose-villaganas-orcullo-and-charnel).